# Draw route on Map Wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, bing-maps

I've got map control:

```
<wpf:Map x:Name="EventMapBing" CredentialsProvider="MY API" MouseDoubleClick="EventMapBing_MouseDoubleClick">
```

I know how to obtain whole route:

```
private void GetResponse(Uri uri, Action<Response> callback)
{
    WebClient wc = new WebClient();
    wc.OpenReadCompleted += (o, a) =>
    {
        if (callback != null)
        {
            DataContractJsonSerializer ser = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(Response));
            callback(ser.ReadObject(a.Result) as Response);
        }
    };
    wc.OpenReadAsync(uri);
}
```

And to get data:

```
 string from = "gdansk";
            string to = "sopot";
            string query =
                string.Format(
                    "https://dev.virtualearth.net/REST/V1/Routes/Driving?wp.0={0}&wp.1={1}&optmz=distance&routeAttributes=routePath&key=MYAPI",
                    from, to);
            Uri geocodeRequest = new Uri(query);

            GetResponse(geocodeRequest, (x) =>
            {
                var route = x.ResourceSets[0].Resources[0] as Route;
                var wholeRoute = route.RouteLegs;
                //  x.ResourceSets[0].Resources[0].
            });
```

So my "wholeRoute" variable is RouteLeg[] type. How can I display that route on my bing map control?

Comment: Take a look at this. There are links in there to other posts and at least one article. I didn't dig through it but I think somewhere in all that lot ought to be something relevant. https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/d7b0b272-35f3-4724-8546-dce9bd8b1e3d/wpf-bing-map-control-how-to-draw-route-lines?forum=bingmapssilverlightwpfcontrols

Comment: @Andy Thank you, that really helped! Everything works now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I've done it:

Simply just resolve coordinates, create LocationCollection and apply it to MapPolyLine. Last part is adding MapPolyLine to bing map controller.

```
  Route route = r.ResourceSets[0].Resources[0] as Route;

                        double[][] routePath = route.RoutePath.Line.Coordinates;
                        LocationCollection locs = new LocationCollection();

                        for (int i = 0; i < routePath.Length; i++)
                        {
                            if (routePath[i].Length >= 2)
                            {
                                locs.Add(new Microsoft.Maps.MapControl.WPF.Location(routePath[i][0], routePath[i][1]));
                            }
                        }

                        MapPolyline routeLine = new MapPolyline()
                        {
                            Locations = locs,
                            Stroke = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Blue),
                            StrokeThickness = 5
                        };

                        MyMap.Children.Add(routeLine);
```